# Как выделить определенные дни в monthcalendar данными из бд?

Tags: c#, winforms

Хочу вывести, но в выдает ошибку на строке `DateTime myVacation1 = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(reader["ДатаВылета"]));` Я знаю, что она не верная, скорее всего строка полностью неправильная. Данные в бд access хранятся в ввиде даты/время, в данном случае дата, пример (17.06.2022) Код:

```
private void Data2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    monthCalendar2.Visible = true;
    OleDbCommand t1 = new OleDbCommand();
    t1.Connection = MyConn;
    t1.CommandText = ("SELECT ДатаВылета FROM Рейсы WHERE Класс = @CL AND ГородаВылета = @Depcity AND ГородаПрилета = @arrcity AND ДатаВылета = @dat1");
    t1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CL", comboBox4.Text);
    t1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Depcity", comboBox1.Text);
    t1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@arrcity", comboBox2.Text);
    t1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dat1", Data1.Text);
    OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    DataTable tablo = new DataTable();
    ad.SelectCommand = t1;
    using (OleDbDataReader reader = t1.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            DateTime myVacation1 = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(reader["ДатаВылета"]));
            monthCalendar2.AddBoldedDate(myVacation1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает? Вы уверены, что `reader["ДатаВылета"]` это строка? Вы уверены, что в строке целое число со значением не более, чем `int.MaxValue`?

Answer (score 2):

Использовать хранение в базе данных даты-времени в виде строки - это изысканный способ самому себе *сделать хуже*. Потому что Вы получаете неопределенность в формате, в котором надо вводить дату и время, а также проблемы с сортировкой, сравнением и т.п. штуками, которых мы ожидаем от базы данных.

Поясню подробнее.

Если дату-время хранить в виде строки, то возникают следующие проблемы:

1. Мы начинаем зависеть от формата. Потому что `2022-06-06 16:25:00.000` и `Jun, 2022, 06 16:25` - это одно и то же по сути, но совсем не одно и то же в записи в виде строки. А если хранить в виде DateTime - то и `Jun, 2022, 06 16:25`, и `2022-06-06 16:25:00.000` - это просто два формата одного и того же значения
2. Возникают проблемы при сравнении "больше-меньше". Ну, просто потому, что строки не обязаны подчиняться тем же правилам, что и значения, которые они представляют. Опять же, результат сравнения зависит от формата.
3. еще одна проблема со временем, которое хранится в базе данных - это часовые пояса. Даже в "примере с самолётом" есть "локальное" время города, из кторого вылетает рейс, и есть "локальное" время города, куда рейс прилетает. Но на самом делел - это одно ито же время, если хранить его в UTC, например. А про каждый город знать, на сколько часов происходит сдвиг относительно UTC

Поэтому исправлять надо комплексно:

1. В базе данных переделывааем поле `ДатаВылета` на тип `DateTime`
2. Вместо `t1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dat1", Data1.Text);` начинаем использовать что то вроде `t1.Parameters.Add("@dat1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dt.Date;`
3. Из за того, что теперь у нас в одном поел есть "дата вылета и время вылета", а в поиске пользователь ввводит именно  "дату вылета" - нужно в SQL-запросе сделать поиск по диапазону, что то вроде `SELECT * FROM Рейсы WHERE Класс = @CL AND ГородаВылета = @Depcity AND ГородаПрилета = @arrcity AND ДатаВылета>=@dat1 AND ДатаВылета<@dat2`

Кроме того, Вас вряд ли интересует именнно время вылета, скорее всего Ваш селект будет спользоваться для заполнения списка рейсов, удовлетворяющих условию, поэтому сделаем сразу `SELECT Класс, ГородаВылета, ГородаПрилета, ДатаВылета FROM Рейсы WHERE Класс = @CL AND ГородаВылета = @Depcity AND ГородаПрилета = @arrcity AND ДатаВылета>=@dat1 AND ДатаВылета<@dat2`

Comment: "*Использовать хранение в базе данных даты-времени в виде строки - это изысканный способ самому себе сделать хуже*", эх сказал бы мне кто-то эти слова года два назад...

Comment: А почему надо переделывать ДатаВылета на тип DateTime?

Comment: У меня строка с ("@dat1", Data1.Text); , так как дата из календаря выводится в textbox с именем Data1. Спасибо за совет насчёт поиска  диапазона дат.

Comment: @АлександрШтейнер потому что дата может быть локальная, в виде миллисекунд прошедших с 1970 года..а если поле у вас в виде строки - он туда может ввести что угодно, а вам потом это конвертить в дату. Еще существует часовой пояс, в бд есть типы "with timezone"/"without timezone" (отличается по названиям, но суть одна).. для этого уже существует тип DateTime, вы же целые числа не храните в виде строки, вот и дату не надо

Comment: @АлександрШтейнер - я немного дополнил ответ - пояснил

Comment: @S.H., я новичок, извиняюсь, что туплю, но у меня тип данных в бд access стоит Дата и время у столбца ДатаВылета, это тоже самое, что DateTime?

Comment: @АлександрШтейнер - прошу прощения, я немного прошляпил, что там access, и уже начал писать пример для MS SQL. Но - вроде да, любая штука, которая по смыслу содержит дату и время - это то, что нужно

Comment: @S.H., а строчку с переделывать? Цитирую выше "У меня строка с ("@dat1", Data1.Text); , так как дата из календаря вылета выводится в textbox с именем Data1. Спасибо за совет насчёт поиска диапазона дат.", а так за советы спасибо, на будущее учту

Comment: @АлександрШтейнер - я сейчас попробую написать пример кода и добавить в ответ. у Вас в форме всё таки "календарик" или текстбокс? Потому что календарь умеет "отдавать" селектнутое значение в виде DateTime

Comment: @S.H., у меня на нажатие TextBox появляется monthcalendar, где при выборе даты в monthcalendar, выводится дата в сам textbox, если надо могу саму программу скинуть

Comment: @АлександрШтейнер - сам элемент monthcalendar я знаю, но, видимо, он у Вас используется "более сложно": при нажатии на textbox появляется monthcalendar, а потом textbox используется как "промежуточное хранилище" для выбранного из календаря значения, так? И еще один вопрос: я посмотрел - в результате выполнения Вашего кода некотрые дни в monthCalendar должны "заболдится", если в эти дни есть нужные рейсы - так?

Comment: @S.H. Да, у меня сделано так, я хотел сделать после, того как пойму, как выделять дни в календаре, так чтобы при выборе определенных городов выделялись определенные дни вылета, и если например выбрал дату 23.06.2022, и есть полёт обртано на даты 21.06.2022 и 24.06.2022, их выделяют, но нельзя было бы выбрать "прошедшую" дату.